# how to get server response in PHP html5 upload

Tags: php, javascript, html

I got a part of html5 upload script, it is as follow:

```
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
            alert('done');
            var i =xhr.getResponseHeader('header');
            alert(i.status);
        }, false);

        xhr.open("post", "upload/process", true);

        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json-rpc");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.fileName);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.fileSize);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", file.type);

        xhr.send(file);
```

And My PHP is as follow:

```
    $name = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME'];
    $path = '/upload/';
    if(file_put_contents($path.$name, "php://input"))
    {
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'sucess', 'name'=>$name)); 
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'error'));
    }
```

I want to grab the Json response from server and show it. So far I don't know how, I tried

```
var i =xhr.getResponseHeader('header');
alert(i.status);
```

But i got a error "NULL".

Comment: Please note, there is nothing wrong with the code, it works great, check out the demo. I just want to know how to grab the JSON response from server.

Comment: fyi, it's *success* with two `c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MDC - XMLHttpRequest documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_xmlhttprequest) provides good information.

The response is contained in `xhr.responseText`. So you have to do:

```
xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
    alert('done');
    var i = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    alert(i.status);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need quotes around "upload/process" in the line:

```
xhr.open("post", upload/process, true);
```

That is sort of a guess though.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I'm not really sure what the issue is then.